# Remove boot partition item from file manager in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but in the file manager left bar a 72 MB disk partition is shown. I think  it is the EFI partition. How can I remove this?

[image: nautilus left bar]

Comment: _Don't delete it_ for it may be the EFI partition which houses /boot/efi and your system would not boot without it. Please run _lsblk | grep -v  'loop' | 'tempfs'  && df -h | grep -v 'loop' | 'tempfs'_ then highlight the resulting text and copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C then come back here, click [edit] and paste that text into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: When I run lsblk | grep -v 'loop' | 'tempfs' && df -h | grep -v 'loop' | 'tempfs'        result was following:   tempfs: command not found

Comment: _tempfs_ is a filtering term for grep. Use _lsblk | grep -v 'loop'   && df -h | grep -v 'loop'_ then delete the _tempfs_ lines once you paste the results into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remount the drive with the `x-gvfs-hide`, for example: `mount -o remount,x-gvfs-hide /dev/sda1` which will hide it immediately.

Then you can also update `/etc/fstab` to make this permanent, but ensure you make a backup of it first.

To see how the device is currently mounted, you cat `grep sda1 /etc/mtab`

Comment: Thank you. _mount_ _-o remount,x-gvfs-hide /dev/sda1_ helped

Comment: fantastic! If it has solved the problem, please upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: sorry I am new here. forgot  @ThankYee